# Lat long shows up far away from intended point

Tags: javascript, coordinates, latitude-longitude, coordinate-transformation

I'm trying to use the [EPA's TRI database](http://iaspub.epa.gov/enviro/efservice/tri_facility/state_abbr/VA/rows/499:700) to get all the hazardous-materials factories in a certain area, such as Virginia. However, doing this requires converting the location from degrees-minutes-seconds to decimal latitude/longitude. I used this formula:

```
var long = deg + min/60 + sec/3600
```

However, when I plot the points on a map, most of them end up clustered near Afghanistan, with two in India and one lonely marker off in Denmark. I only used data from Virginia, and the database is only for the U.S. anyways.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I'm using Javascript and Google Maps, and this is the link to the [locations API](http://www.epa.gov/enviro/facts/ef_restful.html)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Somehow, when I multiply the longitude by -1, it moves it to the right spot... oh well.